# Angular Mat-List: How to fix avatar text alignment issue with name and description?

Tags: angular, list, frameworks, mat-list

I have Mat list like this

```
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <span>Aplikasi Sparepart</span>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
  <button mat-button>Tambah Sparepart</button>
</mat-toolbar>

<div class="container">
  <mat-list>
    <mat-list-item>
      <img matListAvatar src="assets/avatar.png" width="35" height="35" alt="...">
      <h5 matLine>Nama Lengkap</h5>
      <span matLine>
        nama@domain.com
      </span>
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-list>
</div>
```

name n description not beside avatar, but bottom the avatar...

please help me...

i try on stackblitz working well, but on my pc error name n description bottom avatar